# Javascript not working on wordpress template

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I know that similar issues with not working JS on wordpress are there on StackOverflow, but I didn't find solution, as I am not very into code, it just stopped working.

I have bought a template on MyThemeShop. Everything was working fine, but as I was doing some changes on Theme Options, it somehow breaks. Now I can't use some plugins (monsterinsight) or even create and edit new content.

When I change to another template, everything works as it should. I have tried to delete template and download it from MyThemeShop again, but even this did not work.

Support on MyThemeShop stopped answering me, so I don't know, what else should I try. Anyone has the similar issue with MyThemeShop tepmplates? Thanks for any hint and answer.

Comment: Try updating wordpress

Comment: I did. I have also tried to reinstall/remove plugins, but still nothing.

Comment: Do you know exactly what theme options you changed (and from what to what)?